# Less, multiple imports

Tags: less

I thought within Less you could do imports at the rule level?

e.g. given two Less files with identical variable names but different values

```
@import (reference) 'file1.less'

.myrule1
{ 
  @import (reference) 'file2.less'
  // use varA from file2
}

.myrule2
{ 
  // use varA from file1
}
```

Is this not allowed, it doesn't seem to be in the latest Less version

Failing that can you do this

```
@import (reference) 'file2.less'
.myrule1
{ 
  // use varA from file2
}

@import (reference) 'file1.less'
.myrule2
{ 
  // use varA from file1
}

@import (reference) 'file2.less'
.myrule3
{ 
  // use varA from file2 again
}
```

What am I trying to accomplish here? Kendo UI has multiple themes with colours for grids, headers, etc. Within my less file I want to make something like this

```
.BlackBasedThemes
{
 @import one of the black themes

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor;
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}

.NonBlackBasedThemes
{
 @import one of the not black themes

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor;
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}
```

And then within my code the body gets the NonBlackBasedThemes or NonBlackBasedThemes class. I can just add a MyDiv, etc class to a div and get the theme appropriate colour.

Comment: See [`once`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-once) and [`multiple`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-multiple).

Comment: The question is more one about scope, can you restrict an import to just the rule it's contained within? Although I grant that does seem to answer the second question.

Comment: Also can you combine them? It seems as though I would want import (reference) (multiple) but that didn't seem to compile

Comment: By a comma, e.g.: `@import (reference, multiple, less, optional) "file.less";` Also are you sure you need `reference` in this case? Do the imported files contain anything except variables?

Comment: >can you restrict an import to just the rule it's contained within - yes. >The question is more one about scope - than you'd better reflect this in its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I thought within Less you could do imports at the rule level?
e.g. given two Less files with identical variable names but different values
```

When using lessc 2.4.0 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript] i can do:

black.less:

```
@tooltipBackgroundColor: black;
```

white.less:

```
 @tooltipBackgroundColor: white;
```

Then the following code:

```
.BlackBasedThemes
{
 @import "black";

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor;
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}

.NonBlackBasedThemes
{
 @import "white";

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor;
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}
```

compiles into:

```
.BlackBasedThemes .MyDiv {
  background-color: black;
}
.NonBlackBasedThemes .MyDiv {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Indeed you do not need the `reference` keyword (but it should also work when using it). It is not easy to see what your problem is.

Notice that you can also import one of the files into the global scope:

```
 @import "black"; // sets `@tooltipBackgroundColor` for the global scope
.BlackBasedThemes
{

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor; // uses `@tooltipBackgroundColor` from the global scope
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}

.NonBlackBasedThemes
{
 @import "white";// sets `@tooltipBackgroundColor` for only the local scope

  .MyDiv
  {
    background-color: @tooltipBackgroundColor;// uses `@tooltipBackgroundColor` from the local scope
  }
   // whole bunch of other stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. It seems that what I thought should have worked didn't and now I'm unsure as to why, but at least now that I know it should I can investigate more

Comment: try to create a live example (fiddle or codepen) to show what won't work

Comment: The one key difference straight away is that I use (reference) because those files hold a lot more than I need, but I'll try to reproduce

Comment: I'm not sure how to host the external js files, I don't think kendo less files are on a cdn and I don't have an account anywhere. That being said there's hardly any detail so I've done the first part as another question: Why does reference bring in details that aren't used?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429159/less-reference-not-working

I'll try to reproduce the other part next