# Less, reference not working

Tags: less

My understanding of reference is that it should only include the bits of the imported file it needs. Here it seems to be bringing in other parts?

Main file

```
.FadedGrid
{
    @import (reference)  './kendo.less';

    .k-grid-header th
    {
        background-color: @input-background-color;
    }
}
```

kendo.less file

```
@input-background-color: #000;

/* Nothing from here is used*/
@import "theme.less";
```

theme.less file

```
.UnrelatedRule
{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

output

```
.FadedGrid .UnrelatedRule {
  background-color: #000;
}
.FadedGrid .k-grid-header th {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Why is UnrelatedRule in there? NB It doesn't make a difference if I change it to

```
@import (reference) "theme.less";
```

Comment: which version of Less do you use? This should be fixed in the latest release (or code base), see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2464

Comment: lessc -version, lessc 2.4.0 (Less Compiler) [JavaScript]

Comment: I've also reproduced the other issue. I've raised another question as least the details are clear then. It might be related

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429459/less-producing-the-wrong-output

Comment: well i see now. Cause the nesting cause your issue it is possible more related to https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1851

Comment: Just updated the less version (I thought I was on the latest) but I have the same issue. This is in less 2.5.0.

Obviously in this case it's not important but in my real scenario the file includes a lot of code. So a 2k less file expands to a 126k css file