# less, producing the wrong output

Tags: less

Main file

```
@import (reference)  './kendo1.less';

.FadedGrid
{
    @import (reference)  './kendo2.less';
}

.FadedGrid
{
    @import (reference)  './kendo2.less';

    .k-grid-header th
    {
        background-color: @input-background-color;
    }
}
```

kendo1.less

```
@input-background-color: #000;
```

kendo2.less

```
@input-background-color: #fff;
```

This produces

```
.FadedGrid .k-grid-header th {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

But the colour here should be #ffffff, not #000000

Comment: Your mistake is in not using [`multiple`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-multiple) with the second `'./kendo2.less'` import (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414217).  W/o `multiple` the second import is ignored and `.k-grid-header th` uses the variable set in the global scope e.g. the one imported with `'./kendo1.less'`.

Comment: I'm out so can't check but that sounds right, thanks for that.

Comment: Yep, that was it, thanks. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 1):

You need to change you import from reference to multiple. If you set it to reference it seems to ignore the duplicate imports of the same file.

Import options: http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options

Example:

```
@import (reference)  './kendo1.less';

.FadedGrid
{
  @import (multiple)  './kendo2.less';
}

.FadedGrid
{
      @import (multiple)  './kendo2.less';

  .k-grid-header th
  {
    background-color: @input-background-color;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
/* Generated by less 2.4.0 */
.FadedGrid .k-grid-header th {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Credit should go to @seven-phases-max. I really just tested his comment and put it in answer form.

Comment: I've already tested his comment and said so, "Yep, that was it, thanks"

Comment: I was putting it in answer form for future reference because seven-phases-max did not.